# Java - processing Marklogic eval response giving JSON Documents

Tags: java, marklogic

I have a MarkLogic XQuery eval call that returns a lists of strings. I use the below code to process the results.  I have another call that returns a list of Json Documents but I can't see how to get EvalResult to give me a JsonDocument document. How do I change the below code to process Json Documents?

```
   public static ArrayList<String> getStringList(DatabaseClient client, String query)
   {
      ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
      ServerEvaluationCall eval = client.newServerEval();
      EvalResultIterator eri = eval.xquery(query).eval();
      while (eri.hasNext())
      {
         EvalResult er = eri.next();
         String s = er.getString();
         strings.add(s);
      }
      return strings;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

First, let me suggest that you only use eval as a last resort as it may open a security hole.  Injection attacks aren't possible if you never send code from the client to be executed on the server.  Start first with the out-of-the-box features, and if those aren't enough, consider writing a [resource extension](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/resourceservices) instead of using eval.  Two examples are [ResourceExtension](https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/blob/develop/src/main/java/com/marklogic/client/example/cookbook/ResourceExtension.java) and [JavascriptResourceExtension](https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/blob/develop/src/main/java/com/marklogic/client/example/cookbook/JavascriptResourceExtension.java).

But to answer your question, change this:

```
     String s = er.getString();
```

to this:

```
     JacksonHandle handle = er.get(new JacksonHandle());
     JsonNode json = handle.get();
```

or this shortcut:

```
     JsonNode json = er.getAs(JsonNode.class);
```

For a complete example, see handling of myArray and myObject [EvalTest.evalAndInvokeXQuery](https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/marklogic/client/test/EvalTest.java#L132-L152) (and of course, [runAndTestXQuery](https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/marklogic/client/test/EvalTest.java#L271)) and [evaltest.xqy](https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/blob/develop/src/test/resources/evaltest.xqy).

These Jackson handles work the same whether you're getting JSON results from a document read, search, or eval.  You can read more about the io shortcuts [here](http://www.marklogic.com/blog/io-shortcut-marklogic-java-client-api/). For more sample code with Jackson, see [JacksonHandleExample](https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/blob/develop/src/main/java/com/marklogic/client/example/handle/JacksonHandleExample.java), [JacksonHandleTest](https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/marklogic/client/test/JacksonHandleTest.java), [JacksonStreamTest](https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/marklogic/client/test/JacksonStreamTest.java), and [JacksonDatabindTest](https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/marklogic/client/test/JacksonDatabindTest.java).

Comment: Thank you very much - I will try that.

Comment: Yes that worked!!  FYI - I was so close - what I had tried (among other things) was er.getAs(JacksonHandle.class) but that just gave an exception.